# ESXi Tesla passthrough enabled but not assignable

Tags: vmware-esxi, passthrough, nvidia

I am facing an issue with an ESXi ( 6.7.0 Update 1 ) and the passthrough of a GPU card (NVIDIA Tesla P4).

The GPU card is listed in the "Passthrough capable" PCI Devices section as "Enabled / Needs reboot" but no matter the number of time the ESXi is rebooted, the GPU card does not move to the "Passthrough active" list and thus it cannot be assigned to any VMs.

Note that there is another NVIDIA GPU (RTX 2080) on the system and that one is able to work correctly with the passthrough.

Checking on the ESXi host via the SSH console, I can see in /etc/vmware/esx.conf that the device is listed with "passthru" as owner.

```
/device/00000:007:00.0/owner = "passthru"
```

[Passthrough capable devices list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiNE0.png)

What else can be done to find the root cause of the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with a specific PCIe port (x8 instead of x16), card moved to another PCIe port on the same host and now the passthrough is active.