# PCI at NVIDA Tesla P 100 in shared pass through mode is disabled

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vmware-esx, pci, nvidia

I have successfully completed `NVIDIA Tesla P100` Grid Setup on the `vSphere` Host Server with `VMware ESXI 6.7`.While trying to add `PCI` devices in the VM, the option to choose PCI devices is shown as in the `“Add Other Hardware”` setting in `“Virtual Hardware"`. Please refer the screenshot below.

[image]

I can add PCI devices when NVIDIA is used as `Direct I/O passthrough`, but when I use `NVIDIA shared passthrough`, PCI device is shown as disabled. As, I need to share the GPU, I’m forced to use NVIDIA shared passthrough.

`nvidia-smi`  is as follows

```
 NVIDIA-SMI 410.91       Driver Version: 410.91       CUDA Version: N/A      

| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla P100-PCIE...  On   | 00000000:3B:00.0 Off |                  Off |
| N/A   31C    P0    26W / 250W |     31MiB / 12287MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

The result of `#esxcli graphics host get` is as follows.

```
 Default Graphics Type: SharedPassthru
   Shared Passthru Assignment Policy: Performance
```

Kindly help me to enable the PCI at NVIDA Tesla P 100 in shared pass through mode.

Comment: Did you reboot the host after installing and configuring the GPU vib?

Comment: @TimListon , Yes I did. Is there any command for enabling PCI device at VMWare ESXI 6.7

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but take a look at this related question and their solution and see if it might relate to your situation.  https://serverfault.com/questions/950161/esxi-tesla-passthrough-enabled-but-not-assignable?rq=1

Comment: @TimListon Thanks for your reply,  I am able to direct I/O passthrough the Tesla P100 gpu to VM but I am not able to do the shared passthrough the same to VM

Answer (score 0):

i know this question is old, but i just ran into the same "issue". you cannot use vGPU without vCenter. you must install a vCenter to get the add shared pci ressource option for a VM.